# Why directive <IfDefine> not working (Apache 2.4)?

Tags: apache, security, mod-rewrite, ifdefine

I'm trying to block a IP list generated by CustomLog using IfDefine to avoid log ip again, but it's not working. I changed CustomLog conditional and something bizarre behavior can be observed:

```
RewriteMap blacklist txt:/var/www/blacklist.log
RewriteCond   ${blacklist:%{REMOTE_ADDR}|NOT-FOUND} !=NOT-FOUND [OR]
RewriteCond   ${blacklist:%{REMOTE_HOST}|NOT-FOUND} !=NOT-FOUND
RewriteRule   ^ - [F,E=BLOCKED_IP]

<IfDefine !BLOCKED_IP>
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/xmlrpc\.php$" BAD_BEHAVIOR
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/blacklist.log "%h ## %t BAD_BEHAVIOR \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{User-agent}i\"" env=BLOCKED_IP
</IfDefine>
```

Even when BLOCKED_IP true the code inside IfDefine executes and CustomLog has a inverse conditional... It doesnt make any sense -.-

1. RewriteRule define BLOCKED_IP
2. IfDefine !BLOCKED_IP pass (why?)
3. CustomLog works with a inverse conditional (why again?)
4. blacklist.log has added same IP

Can someone explain this behavior??

Comment: Any progress, did you find an answer? I'm looking to do something similar.

Comment: Nop... it just don't work... I'm using nginx now. =)

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

IfDefine do not work with env variables defined after the start of the application.

It only works with parameter set on the command line via -Dparameter

Answer (score 0):

Usage like `<IfDefine !xxx>` is not supported in Apache 2.4, remove "!" will work normally